# 'Proved itself' or 'Proven itself'?

Tags: grammar, past-participles

I always stuck on this.

> Withania somnifera has proven itself in treating depression and anxiety. OVER 
>   Withania somnifera has proved itself in ...

Whether to use past participle is confusing in such cases. Both seem okay. Another such case is `light-weight software that opens fast` and `light-weighted software that opens fast`.

Comment: My first thought, "The past participle form of *prove* is *proven*, isn't it?" So I was surprised by a dictionary (Macmillan) which lists both *proved* and *proven* as the past participle forms of *prove*.

Comment: I think they can be used interchangeably. Both are accepted past participles of "prove"

Comment: **light-weight**- adjective, **light-weighted**- past participle of **verb light-weight** used as an adjective(if light-weight is used as a verb, as in "Use better algorithm to light-weight this program"). Sounds odd though.

Comment: I suppose it's a past-participle used as an adjective, whereas Light-weight is a pure adjective.

Comment: More comprehensive answers here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/what-is-the-difference-between-proven-and-proved

Comment: Why do you remove your comments? You wrote "light-weighted is an adjective" and I replied. Now without your comment, my comment is giving the idea that I'm talking to myself.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija I removed it because you already mentioned it which I missed at first. You were too quick to respond my comment. Anyway, let it be. It's useful.

Answer (score 0):

They are actually different cases:

In the case of proved/proven, both your sentences are simply a present perfect. The thing is that *proved* and *proven* are both accepted as participles for *prove*.

Just make sure you do not use *both* of them in the same text, as a matter of consistency.

As for light-weight versus light-weighted, *weight* is a noun in the first case, used as an adjective in combination with *light*. In the second case, you have the participle of the **verb** *weight*, also used as an adjective.

In this case there is a difference in meaning as well: the common expression is *light-weight*, meaning that is is not heavy.
*Light-weighted* however implies that someone has weighted it, meaning that weight was deliberately added, but not much (as it was done lightly). *Usually* that is not the implication that is meant :)

Comment: What about a *light-weighted* software - a punch line that can be used to market my product? It's really light-weighted as compared to other software that take too much time to load and thus useless.

Comment: I would call that _light-weight_ actually :)

Comment: that won't be correct I guess. Compare *a proofread (past participle) article* over *a proofread article (simple present)*.

Comment: Light-weight means the opposite of heavy-weight. Why can you not call a piece of software light-weight, and what does that have to do with proofreading? (_a_ software, by the way? it's a mass noun ;) ) I would certainly not worry about people reading light-weight as a verb. In 15 years in IT I have never heard of anyone _light-weighting_ something. Same for 40 years outside IT by the way...

Comment: I tried to make my point clear using *read -past participle* and *read -present simple* as compared to *weighted* and *weight* respectively. **Softwares** has already come and is approved. It's not a mass noun anymore, by the way ;)

Comment: I still do not understand your issue with _light-weight_. Nobody thinks a _heavy-weight_ boxing champion is weighting anything. As for software: it _is_ a mass noun, even _if_ it may seem acceptable in some circumstances to use it differently. I guess then you process informations with it. - _A proofread article_ cannot possibly be a present simple by the way. The _article_ makes it a noun with an adjective.